# Fullscreen DatePicker inside Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, datepicker, android-datepicker

I trying to display the datePicker and timePicker widget inside an activity I'm calling with startActivityForResult. Both pickers should match the parent layout width. In my case, it works with timePicker but the datePicker doesn't fill out the entire screen.

I tried measuring the display size programmatically and setting the layoutparams of datePicker inside onResume. But unfortunately, it didn't work.

How can I implement the datePicker widget so it stretches to the width of the parent layout?

datePicker screenshot

[image]

timePicker screenshot

[image]

activity_date_time_picker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

onResume method in DateTimePickerActivity:

```
/* ... */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) datePicker.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    datePicker.setLayoutParams(params);
}
/* ... */
```

Comment: may be you should something like this:

imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**MainActivity.java** Apply theme in to Constructor of date picker (R.style.AppTheme)

---

```
 DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme, this, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            return datePickerDialog;
```